# NuSoap / PHP Object as Input to .NET Web Service - Can't Get More Than One Value In The Nested Object Array

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, nusoap

Ahhhhhh!!  I need another set of eyes.  I have been working on this project that uses nusoap and PHP through a .NET web service.  The issue I am having is that the arrays within the main object array NEVER form any XML past one element in the array.  The request is successful with one element in the array, but can never form the XML with more one element.  SO the XML request formed is always:
"`<PictureIDs><long>1466020</long></PictureIDs>`"

BUT should really be:

```
<PictureIDs><long>1466020</long><long>1444431</long></PictureIDs>
```

So it works, but can only work with one PictureIDs with success - but never the 2nd one....I don't get what I'm doing wrong.  All I want is to have multiple PictureIDs passed into the PictureIDs array...does anybody have any better ideas on how to make this happen?  You can see the REQUEST XML that gets generated - BUT it JUST SKIPS the second PictureIDs.

---

**I'VE TRIED THE BASIC WAY:**

```
$create_export_request = array(
    'exportRequest'=>array(
        'Credentials'=>array('UserID'=>12345),
        'ApplicationID'=>1,
        'PictureIDs'=>array('long'=>1444431,'long'=>1466020),
        'ExportType'=>'40',
        'ExportOption'=>'ALLOW_DOWNLOAD',
        'EmailFrom'=>'from@me.com',
        'RequireLogin'=>'false',
        'RetainFiles'=>'false',
        'PackageCompressionType'=>'ZIP'
        )
        );

$client = new nusoap_client('http://zzzz.WebService.asmx?WSDL',true);
$result = $client->call('ManageProcess',$create_export_request);
```

**REQUEST:**

POST /V1.2.5/ExportInterface/EMService.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: dmr2.spe.sony.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://WebService.zzz/ManageProcess"
Content-Length: 1225

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2996="http://tempuri.org"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ManageProcess xmlns="http://zzzz.WebService.asmx"><exportRequest><Credentials><UserID>12345</UserID></Credentials><ApplicationID>1</ApplicationID><PictureIDs><long>1466020</long></PictureIDs><ExportType>40</ExportType><ExportOption>ALLOW_DOWNLOAD</ExportOption><EmailFrom>from@me.com</EmailFrom><RequireLogin>false</RequireLogin><RetainFiles>false</RetainFiles><PackageCompressionType>ZIP</PackageCompressionType></exportRequest></ManageProcess></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**TO THIS WAY THAT BREAKS UP THE ARRAYS:**

```
$credentials = array(
    'UserID' => 12345
);

$pictureIds = array(
    'long'=>1444431,
    'long'=>1466020
);

$exportOptions = array(
    'Credentials'=>$credentials,
    'PictureIDs'=>$pictureIds,
    'ApplicationID'=>1,
    'ExportType'=>'40',
    'ExportOption'=>'ALLOW_DOWNLOAD',
    'RetainFiles'=>'false',
    'RequireLogin'=>'false',
    'PackageCompressionType'=>'ZIP'
);

$client = new nusoap_client(http://zzzz.WebService.asmx?WSDL',true);
$er = array('exportRequest' => $exportOptions);
$result = $client->call('ManageProcess', array('parameters' => $er));
```

**REQUEST:**

POST /V1.2.5/ExportInterface/EMService.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: dmr2.spe.sony.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://WebService.zzz/ManageProcess"
Content-Length: 1225

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2996="http://tempuri.org"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ManageProcess xmlns="http://zzzz.WebService.asmx"><exportRequest><Credentials><UserID>12345</UserID></Credentials><ApplicationID>1</ApplicationID><PictureIDs><long>1466020</long></PictureIDs><ExportType>40</ExportType><ExportOption>ALLOW_DOWNLOAD</ExportOption><EmailFrom>from@me.com</EmailFrom><RequireLogin>false</RequireLogin><RetainFiles>false</RetainFiles><PackageCompressionType>ZIP</PackageCompressionType></exportRequest></ManageProcess></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively overwriting a key "long" with another value here:

```
$create_export_request = array(
...
'exportRequest'=>array(
    'PictureIDs'=>array('long'=>1444431,'long'=>1466020),
```

Have a look at that array before sending. It is more likely that you either just add them to the array like `'PictureIDs'=>array(1444431, 1466020)` or some way similar.
Hope that helps.